# Error reading data from MySQL table 1064 (42000)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a table using python in MySQL workbench but everytime that I run this I get an error saying: "Error reading data from MySQL table 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
try:
     connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                          database='project2',
                                          user='root',
                                          password='123')
     sql_select_Query = ("CREATE TABLE customer (custID int,custName VARCHAR(25), zip int, city VARCHAR(25), state VARCHAR(25)")
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
     print("customer Table is Created in the Database")
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
     print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
finally:
     if connection.is_connected():
          connection.close()
          cursor.close()
          print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

I have been trying everything different ways to do it but I keep getting errors

Comment: The errors refers to a syntax in your sql query. Fix the query and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

You simply missed a "`)`" in your sql, try this :

```
sql_select_Query = ("CREATE TABLE customer (custID int,custName VARCHAR(25), zip int, city VARCHAR(25), state VARCHAR(25))")
```

please be more thorough in reading your own code.
here's a simple trick if you find that error again:

1. Open your DBMS
2. Use your raw SQL there
3. Make sure it works
4. put it in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
sql_select_Query = ("CREATE TABLE customer (custID int,custName VARCHAR(25), zip int, city VARCHAR(25), state VARCHAR(25)")
```

you missed `)` at the end of query command:

```
sql_select_Query = ("CREATE TABLE customer (custID int,custName VARCHAR(25), zip int, city VARCHAR(25), state VARCHAR(25))")
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the parenthesis at the very end:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (custID int,custName VARCHAR(25), zip int, city VARCHAR(25), state VARCHAR(25));
```